# How to save/export designer pages in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, designer, table-relationships

I have many pages in the Designer Tab of PHPMyAdmin. How do I export it? So I can import it in any other laptop.
[One of my pages in the PHPMyAdmin Designer Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpqfQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

The Designer layouts are saved in the phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage database (usually `phpmyadmin`) in the table `pma__designer_coords`. You can copy that table to the other system (or values from within that table) to duplicate your settings.